# Parallax code not working, not showing up in chrome preview

Tags: html, css, parallax

I am trying to make a parallax for the first time and am having troubles.

I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6CQ7DYni7Bg) tutorial and then trying to work backwards. The code isn't working however and I'm not sure where I made the mistake, I jumped around to a few other tutorials and tried to adjust the names of different divs and CSS blocks so the code is a bit messy right now.

```css
.html {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.body {
  max-width: 30px color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  perspective: 1px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  height: 100% overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: "Luna"
}

header {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding 30vw 0 5vw;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: inherit;
  width: 100vw;
}

header h1 {
  margin-top: -100px;
}

header,
header:before {
  background: 50% 50% / cover;
}

header::before {
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  background-image: url(picture1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  transform-origin: center center 0;
  transform: tranlasteZ(-1px) scale(2);
  z-index: -1;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

header * {
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em 0;
}

.image1 {
  background: url('img/(picture1.jpg') no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 500px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Schade's Parralax</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <p>Hi My name is schade I wrote this so I could have a test of my program.</p>
    <div class="image1"> </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention specs: I'm running this on window, testing in chrome, my OS is updated, and my editor is Sublime.

Comment: First of all you need to fix typos and simple code errors like missing semi-colons.

Comment: are you interested in a solution using jquery or do want to keep it pure html + css?

Comment: html and css - question answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In first use a container element and add a background image to the `container` with a specific `height`. Then use the `background-attachment: fixed` to create the actual parallax effect.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 75px;
}

.parallax {
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/36764/marguerite-daisy-beautiful-beauty.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260');
  height: 100%;
  /* Parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed; // Try to remove this property
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.content {
  height: 300px;
  line-height: 300px;
  background: #ededed;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="parallax"></div>

  <div class="content">
    <h1>content</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="parallax"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Some mobile devices have a problem with `background-attachment: fixed`. You can use `media queries` to turn off the parallax effect:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1366px) {
    .parallax {
        background-attachment: scroll;
    }
}
```

More info about [fixed](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp) property.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the help! What exactly is the "fixed" portion of the code doing?